# How to display the count of specific value on Label when this value is the today date

Tags: sql, vb.net, label

I have a SQL Server database with an `Appointment` table which contains `Name` and `Date` columns. I want to display the count of each record (on a `Label`) IF the `Date` column is equal to "todays date".  I also want to display the number of appointments for the current month on another Label. How can I do that? I'm using VB.NET.

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?

Comment: Which part of this are you having difficulty with?  Connecting to the DB?  Querying the DB?  Reading the results from the query?  Displaying the results in the label?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: I'm  having difficulty with querying the DB and Displaying the results in the Labels.

Comment: Do you want to use LINQ to SQL, or a data adapter, or do you want to read the results directly with a data reader?  Do you have a preference?

Comment: I prefer reading the results directly with a data reader. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Public Function GetAppointmentsCount(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Integer
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("")
        connection.Open()
        Using command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = "select count([Date]) from Appointment where [Date] >= @StartDate and [Date] <= @EndDate"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", startDate)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EndDate", endDate)
            Return CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
Dim startOfDay As Date = Date.Today
Dim endOfDay As Date = startOfDay.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
Dim dayCount As Integer = GetAppointmentsCount(startOfDay, endOfDay)

Dim startOfMonth As Date = New Date(Date.Today.Year, Date.Today.Month, 1)
Dim endOfMonth As Date = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddTicks(-1)
Dim monthCount As Integer = GetAppointmentsCount(startOfMonth, endOfMonth)

lblDayCount.Text = dayCount.ToString() & " appointment(s) today"
lblMonthCount.Text = monthCount.ToString() & " appointment(s) this month"
```